# UIScrollView not working with multi-views xCode 4.5.2

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, xcode4.5

I am using xCode 4.5.2, I added a `UIScrollView` and I checked **Bounce Horizontally** in IB and `setAlwaysBounceHorizontal` in `viewDidAppear` to `YES` and it works fine, but apparently the `UIScrollView` has been resized when I load another view and return to it, although the `viewDidAppear` has `setContentSize`:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(2000, 90)];
[scroller setAlwaysBounceHorizontal:YES];
[scroller setAutoresizesSubviews:NO];
scroller.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
scroller.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
[scroller setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scroller setPagingEnabled:YES];

}
```

Hope to find a solution for this ..

Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

If you created a `scrollView` from nib you have to uncheck the Use **Autolayout** from there:

- Go to your nib.
- Select your view.
- Go to utility window of nib.
- Select First tab form left of utility window.
- UNCHECK Autolayout.